# DJANGO Rest framework - PUT/UPDATE API

Tags: django-rest-framework, crud

I have a problem with creating a PUT request in Django REST.

This is what my code looks like:

**serializer**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
      model = Profile
      fields = ('department', 'monthly_salary', 'tech_stack')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   profile = ProfileSerializer()
   class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'profile')
```

**view**

```
class EmployeeUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):

  queryset = User.objects.all()
  serializer_class = UserSerializer

  def get_object(self):
      user_id = self.kwargs['pk']
      user = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_id)
      return user

  def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      instance = self.get_object()
      data = {
          'username': request.data.get('username'),
          'first_name': request.data.get('first_name'),
          'last_name': request.data.get('last_name'),
          'email': request.data.get('email'),
          'profile': {
              'department': request.data.get('department'),
              'monthly_salary': request.data.get('monthly_salary'),
              'tech_stack': request.data.get('tech_stack')
          }
      }
      user_serializer = UserSerializer(instance, data=data, partial=True)
      if user_serializer.is_valid():
          user_serializer.save()
          return Response(user_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
      return Response(user_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**url**

api/employees/edit/int:pk/

Since I'm working with the built-in User model, I additionally use the Profile model because of some additional columns I needed. I can't do PUT at all because I keep getting the error "detail": "Method "GET" not allowed."

Does anyone see where is the problem and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Check if you have a redirect on the request, it can be http:// to https://, non-www to www., or redirect to leading /

Answer (score 0):

`Method GET not allowed` is when you are sending a GET request to an endpoint which does not have a GET method handler.

Can you check if your request is being sent as a GET request? Because `UpdateAPIView` does not have a GET method. If you are using Postman, you can easily check the UI or the CURL option to see the exact translation of your request.